# Build Failed - Mono C ASM project

Tags: assembly, mono, monodevelop

Im using Mono C for my ASM project. I am using Mac.
I compiled a simple statements with ASM but it builds with error saying *Build failed* .

Here is my code!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{

asm( "mov ah, 09;" );
return 0;
}
```

My question is:
Is Mono C really capable of running of ASM, if yes then whats wrong? configurations? compiler options?

Comment: Is all it said *"build failed"*? It must have said something else...

Comment: it only says "Build failed - check build output for details" nothing more

Comment: What does build output say?

Comment: The weird thing is I cant find the build output. It should be somewhere in project directory but its not there. mmmm

Comment: thanks for your help though, i just found the build output somewhere in the tabs! :)